# What can I do after work to deal with burnout?

Tags: burnout

Already exercising a hour and looking for a new job, quitting currently would not be possible. But I still find my job unbearable and want to just stand up and leave every hour. I can't even focus on finishing a small task early. I think I am burning out but not sure what I can do.

Comment: Talk to your doctor. Burnout is a medical condition that makes you unable to work.

Answer (score 4):

Burnout is strictly related to your work conditions. As long as you do not remove the cause, you will not be able to solve the effect. You might be able to find a solution to slow down at your current job, or you should change jobs (I understand, changing jobs is not the best option for you now).

---

To keep the situation under control somehow, try to separate (in your mind) the job life from the personal life. Completely. Do not take work at home. Do not answer phone calls from colleagues, bosses, suppliers, customers... The more you disconnect and separate, the better.

Try to spend as much of the free time as possible in green areas. The greener, the better. Forests "far" from polluted businesses are the best.

Try o have some physical activity in these green areas. Even walking is better than sitting. In this way, you bring more oxygen to your brain. Of course, remember to breathe - it is not a joke, sometimes we almost stop breathing, unfortunately.

Regardless of where you are, do what you actually enjoy. Read books. Watch movies. Dance. Create furniture or jewelries. Do gardening. Anything is better than nothing.

Get more social - really social, not smartphones and computers and social networks. Be with people. Talk. Laugh. Feel good.

Keep away from toxic people. There are people who just love being / feeling miserable. They are usually successful bringing the misery in the lives of the people around them.

During the weekends, go away from the city. Disconnect from anything reminding of work and stress (even though organizing a going out can be somehow stressful).